# Toggle text + also call method with argument?

Tags: jquery, function, toggle

Im trying to toggle change a text on spacebar press with jquery ( works ) but also try to call a method with custom argument. 
How would below code example needs to me modified to do this? I have tried all kinds of ways but don't understand how to add the argument in. Also please explain how this should work in jquery and what im missing ( as learning point )

My goal is to call the argument with "start" and "stop" on each keypress

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {

        if (e.keyCode == "32"){

          e.preventDefault();
          $(".spacebar_left").text(function(i, v){
            return v === 'PUSH ME' ? 'DON"T PUSH ME' : 'PUSH ME'
            custommethod("start")
           })


        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == "32") {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".spacebar_left").text(function(i, v) {
            if (v === 'PUSH ME') {
                custommethod("start")
                return 'DON"T PUSH ME'
            } else {
                custommethod("end")
                return "PUSH ME"
            }
        })
    }
});
```

*p.s.: in your example `custommethod()` is never called as it goes after
    `return`*